# Firestore document read costs when one new document is added in a snapshot listener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document listener that listens to the top 25 documents similar to this:

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
.limit(to: 25)
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        let cities = documents.map { $0["name"]! }
        print("Current cities in CA: \(cities)")
    }
```

I noticed that when a new document is added that matches the query, the listener returns the top 25 documents (even though only one new document was added).

Am I going to be charged for 25 document reads every time one new document is added with this listener? Or is there any help from caching (since I am using a snapshot listener) that will only charge for one document being added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only charged for the document that was added.  As long as the listener is added, all documents that were part of a prior result set are cached in memory and redelivered to the listener if there is a change.

Comment: Suppose I was subscribed to the latest 20 messages in date order. But let's assume that one of those messages was deleted and the 21st message came in as number 20. Then, will the reading fee be added one more time here? Or maybe 20 + 20?

Comment: @SwiftStarter This answer is telling you exactly what you need to know.  Your case is almost exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that if the document was missing and a new document came in, all the orders would be changed, so there could be a charge for reading 20 again.

*** I thought differently because the above case was added, and my case was deleted and there was an empty space.

I'm glad it's the same case.